# How to make one class classifier to predict probability of belonging to this class?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, classification, prediction

I have a dataset where each line corresponds to the onset of some event A and features here are some parameters that were fixed at this event.
It is necessary to build a model that will take the values of the parameters as input, and the output will give the probability that at such values of the parameters event A will come
I looked at One class SVM, but I understand that it does not give a probability at the output, but simply a mark of -1 or 1. What approach is required?

Comment: Based on the given features, you need to output some probability label. Is this correct? If yes, you can use something like logistic regression.

Answer (score 1):

use `predict_proba` instead of `predict`.

It will give you probability of a particular class being true.